# Grant .NET application admin privileges

Tags: c#, windows, admin, privileges

I created a launcher app (C#/Windows Forms) executing installers and configuring workstation of the current user. It will be the unique entrypoint because the user will not have the write permissions on any directory. So, I have to grant this launcher with admin role. But I don't know how.

Is there a special lib in C# to do it ? Or it's a Windows command ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't create an extra application to begin with. Windows always had such mechanisms. Powershell DSC can configure workstations and run installers already. Even before that, configuration was possible through group policies. What you describe is a solved problem

Comment: The built-in approaches solve problems you haven't consider yet. Who's going to deploy your custom application to the workstations? How and when will it run? What do you do when a new machine is added? Or you need to deploy configuration changes to multiple workstations? How do you script this? How do you *version* the configurations?

Comment: The installers are not real installers but rather zip containing a whole bunch of things to deploy on the station. We wrote installation / configuration manuals, the idea now is to do this automatically. Regarding your other questions, we already have a strategy in place.

Comment: Which is what Powershell DSC does. Group policies also do this, but Powershell DSC allows you to push changes immediately. These things are already automated

Comment: In all cases, it will be necessary to go through a graphical application (users will not launch Power Shell) and to start again from the ZIPs (which are part of a larger business process). I'm amazed that I have to rewrite .NET code in Powershell and recall that PowerShell code from .NET. I will however look on the side of what has been suggested.

Comment: There's no need for *any* UI or user intervention. Never mind the dangerous security elevation, to allow a desktop application to modify the OS. The OS will push the changes to all targeted machines as long as they're powered up. There was no reason to write the Winforms application to begin with.

Comment: How were hundreds of thousands of both small and big companies handling their configuration already? How are banks handling thousands of desktops? That's what group policies are for. The technologies exist since 2000.

Comment: You will not contact our client's IT department to explain your view of things. Isn't' it ? There are constraints that exist, choices that have been made that do not belong to us. We must make do.